# Making a pyspark dataframe column from a list where the length of the list is same as the row count of the dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, pyspark

I have a existing pyspark dataframe which has 170 column and 841 rows. I am looking to add another column to it which is a list of 'string'. The length of the list is 841 and name is **totals**

```
  >>> totals
['165024392279', '672183', '1002643', '202292', '216254163906', '4698279464', '9247442818', '60093051178', '22208366804', '994475', '12174', '9404969384', '32118344368', '857443', '48544', '24572495416', '43802661492', '35686122552', '780813', '35414800642', '661474', '531615', '31962803064', '111295163538', '531671', '25776968294', '78538019255', '152455113964', '39305504103', '325507', '1028244', '82294034461', '715748', '12705147430', '678604', '90303771130', '1372443', '362131', '59079186929', '436218', '79528', '41366', '89254591311'...]
```

One of the ways could be to make a new dataframe and join it with the main dataframe.

```
new_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(**{'3G-fixated voice users':t})for t in totals])
```

So **new_df** has 1 column with 841 rows. And it cannot be joined to the original dataframe as there are no common columns to join upon.

Another half baked approach I could think of is using literals.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions  import array,lit
totals=[str(t) for t in totals]
test_lit = array([array([lit(t) for t in tt]) for tt in totals])
big_df.withColumn('3G-fixated voice users',test_lit)
```

This adds a new column which is of type

```
array<array<string>>
```

and all the values are only in the first row which is not desired.

Is there a way to add a new column from the list when the length of the list is same as number of rows in the dataframe?

Still new to using pyspark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
df = sc.parallelize([(1,2,3,4,5),(6,7,8,9,10),(16,17,18,19,20)]).toDF(['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])
df = df.withColumn("row_id", monotonically_increasing_id())

totals_df = sc.parallelize(['xxx','yyy','zzz']).map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(['totals'])
totals_df = totals_df.withColumn("row_id", monotonically_increasing_id())

final_df = df.join(totals_df, df.row_id == totals_df.row_id)
final_df = final_df.select([c for c in final_df.columns if c not in {'row_id'}])
final_df.show()
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*